# How to calculate where on progress bar x-axis mouse was clicked?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mouseevent

I'm trying to calculate what percent the user clicked on the progress bar container. Ie: if they click in the middle it should pass "50%". But I'm getting incorrect results as the progress bar changes.

```
<template>
  <span class="progress"
        :style="{ width }"
        @click.prevent="onClickProgress($event)">
    <span class="elapsed" :style="{ width: completed }" ref="elapsed"></span>
    <span class="remainder" :style="{ width: remainder }"></span>
  </span>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'progress-bar',
  props: ['percent', 'width'],
  computed: {
    completed() {
      return `${this.percent}%`;
    },
    remainder() {
      return `${100 - this.percent}%`;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onClickProgress($event) {
      // calculate where on progress bar click happened
      const width = $event.currentTarget.clientWidth;
      const elapsedWidth = this.$refs.elapsed.clientWidth;
      const offsetX =  elapsedWidth <  width ? elapsedWidth + $event.offsetX : $event.offsetX;
      const percent = Math.round((offsetX / width) * 100);


      this.$emit('onClickProgress', { percent });
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.progress {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;

  .elapsed {
    display: inline-block;
    height: .5rem;
    background: #E41C69;
  }

  .remainder {
    display: inline-block;
    height: .5rem;
    background: #000;
  }
}
</style>
```

Its got to do with the element clicked, since I have two child elements for elapsed and remainder I think the mouse event is giving me coordinates for this element and not the `.progress` bar which is what I want.

```
    onClickProgress($event) {
      // calculate where on progress bar click happened
      const width = $event.currentTarget.clientWidth;
      const elapsedWidth = this.$refs.elapsed.clientWidth;
      const offsetX =  elapsedWidth <  width ? elapsedWidth + $event.offsetX : $event.offsetX;
      const percent = Math.round((offsetX / width) * 100);

      this.$emit('onClickProgress', { percent });
    },
```

- version 1: https://codesandbox.io/s/op7prxq6z
- version 2: https://codesandbox.io/s/8265mqnr50

Comment: how are you calling that method in parent component?

Comment: i had created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/op7prxq6z) that could help others to debug your code

Comment: its using an event handler `v-on:onClickProgress="onClickProgress"`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i tried this version too, but something isn't right when you try to turn the volume back up. https://codesandbox.io/s/8265mqnr50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky.

I think the problem is that $event.offsetX is based on the target of the click, which could be either the elapsed or remaining component, so you have to compute the offset from the relative offsets from target and currentTarget:

```
  const offsetX = $event.offsetX + $event.target.offsetLeft - $event.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
```

This gives you the offset of the click in the parent, which makes your percentage calculation correct.

My updated, albeit a bit jumbled, sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/llnmj5x7lz

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to better do the progress bar. I tried just using one span, but had issues with the background color so I had to add the `.remainder` span